How to calculate enthalpy in this case?
I have an evaporating side ($T_1$) and a condensing side ($T_2$). Vapor mass is transferred due to partial pressure gradient. The heat transfer in the middle section is $J\Delta H_v$ plus conduction through a non-condensable gas. How do I calculate $\Delta H_v$?

You calculate it at the temperature of the interface.
